# Como hacer un link a archivos que se encuentran fuera del proyecto?

Tags: php

Quiero hacer un listado de los archivos de audio que se encuentran en un directorio fuera de mi proyecto.
Tengo este código pero solo me muestra la lista y al hacer click en el enlace me da un error. Sería posible lo que deseo?

```
$path= "Ruta/Carpeta";
 $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("No se pudo abrir");
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
         if ($file != "." && $file!= ".."){
            $enlace=$path.'/'.$file;
            echo "<a href='$enlace'>".$file."</a><br>";
        }
    }
closedir($dir_handle);
```

Comment: agrega el error que muestra

Comment: Si la ruta que vas a acceder esta fuera de tu directorio del proyecto web no te va a dejar, de todas formas prueba con anteponer a $enlace file:///

Comment: Puedes acceder a la raíz de la ruta con lo siguiente: $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ]  esto devolvera algo como C:\wamp64\www

Comment: @Shadow Paz, si le paso la ruta, por ejemplo 'C:/Carpeta', (C es el disco donde está) me devuelve como error q el navegador no puede abrir esta ruta y si le paso solo 'Carpeta', dice q no puede encontrar la url especificada, en este ultimo caso, busca esa dirección dentro de la carpeta del proyecto

Comment: @Dariel Ramos Diaz de Villegas, ya he probado con lo que me dices y tampoco funciona

Comment: como ya te explique en el comentario anterior no puedes hacer link a un directorio fuera de tu carpeta de proyecto, si es una pagina html, tal vez te pueda funcionar te recomiendo que abras esa página web que quieres acceder desde el navegador y te fijes en la ruta que sale en la barra, ya asi podras formar la string que pasaras al href de tu link. :)

Comment: ok,gracias a todos por su atención